Does Poetry for Python use a nonstandard pyproject.toml? How?
I am considering introducing my organization to Poetry for Python, and I came across this claim:

Avoid using the Poetry tool for new projects. Poetry uses non-standard implementations of key features. For example, it does not use the standard format in pyproject.toml files, which may cause compatibility issues with other tools.

--Modern Good Practices for Python Development
Is this true? I didn't immediately turn up anything searching. What does Poetry do that is nonstandard, in the pyproject.toml or anywhere else?

(inb4: I know some stackoverflow users like to play it fast and loose with what they consider to be "primarily opinion based", so I'm going to get ahead of this one and say no, this question is not primarily opinion based; standards like this are designed to be quite objective, and if you move to close this question as "primarily opinion based" it will only go to show that you fundamentally do not understand that StackOverflow rule or why it exists.)

Seems like you've had a couple of questions closed before ;)

out of curious what package manager are you currently using at your firm?

Some context that's missing here is that poetry's decisions predated the PEP 621 standards, and the usefulness of poetry itself likely influenced the creation and development of those standards.

@DerekRoberts lol We're currently using pip + requirements.txt + venv, which I wouldn't call a package manager even in combination.

Yes, Poetry as of writing still uses its own [tool.poetry.dependencies] table in pyproject.toml.
This is in conflict with PEP621, which specifies among other things that a project's dependencies ought to be listed in [project.dependencies] instead.
There is an issue tracking this here https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3332 and it seems that as of writing support for PEP621 is on the way, with a draft pull request passing checks here: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/9135.
The main downside of this is that other tools do not understand which packages your poetry project depends on. I believe the built packages that you upload to PyPI etc do not suffer from this issue, because poetry during the build process creates correct package metadata with a fixed set of version-pinned dependencies, so pip install your-poetry-package would work just fine to install the dependencies.
In conclusion, in poetry version 2.0, some time soon poetry might be compatible with pyproject.toml standards.

You can also use poetry export to export your pyproject.toml to a requirements.txt that pip can understand.

That was merged days ago, and will be released this year apparently. I think pip was still able to install from poetry's pyproject. https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/321#issuecomment-458205972
